# Accessing ViewBag list via Javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, viewbag

I'm trying to access the elements of a list stored in ViewBag as follows:

```
function equipamentoTemControle() {

   for(i = 0; i < @ViewBag.qtdEquipamentos; i++) {

      var contratocod = @ViewBag.DadosEquipamentos[i].contratocod;
   }

}
```

But when trying to access ***contratocod*** of attribute index ***i*** the Visual Studio says that the variable ***i*** does not exist. How do I access ?

Comment: An integer property

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use

```
var jsonObj = @Html.Raw(Json.Encode(ViewBag.qtdEquipamentos));
```

and then

```
for (i = 0; i < jsonObj .length; i++) { 
var contratocod = jsonObj[i].contratocod;
}
```

Hope this work first encode model in a JSON and then iterate.